# How to connect to and test a post on a mongo database on an ec2 instance

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, amazon-ec2, postman

I'm trying to test a connection to a mongo database on an ec2 instance using postman and node, being new to this I do not know what address I should use in the address bar, I can get it working with localhost, so there is no error with the route.

https://ec2-xx-xx-xx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com:3333/adduser

I have express running the server on port 3333

Comment: Where are you testing from (internal to the VPC or external to the VPC)? Is the subnet you're on private or public?

Comment: i'm trying to connect externally, i have it set as open just for testing.

Comment: Are you on a public subnet though? If you're not assigned a public IP, you won't be able to test your instance (directly). An alternative to direct connecting would be to setup a public facing ELB.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's public or private like I said I'm new to this, sorry for the lack of knowledge, how would I check this???

Comment: Your best bet for now is to go through the [ELB Docs](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/) and throw one in front of your instance if you're just wanting to test. Your subnet settings are under **VPC** -- you can see what subnet your instance is on in the details page on the AWS console.